# When can I use `querySelector` on `shadowRoot`?

Tags: web-component, lit-element

[image]

When can I use `querySelector` on `shadwoRoot`?

I tried it in `connectedCallback`, but it failed.

Comment: Can you share your full component code? without knowing if you're even using shadow dom or how your template looks like it's impossible to answer

Comment: Simple answer: After you create it and populate it.

Answer (score 5):

You should do this in `firstUpdated()`.  That is when the shadowRoot is fully populated.